# Regarding release manager rest api ConfigurationService

Tags: rest, ms-release-management

I was in search of microsoft release manager api to communicate with it and required to load release information programmatically. As there is no documentation of any of the rm api.

On the following blog, it says that there is one rest api to trigger release.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/10/trigger-release-from-build-with-release-management-for-visual-studio-2013-update-3.aspx

From some research by monitoring http communication between release manager client and server, I came to know that it uses similar api. And to load the release data, it uses following service which communicates using xml (Rest service)

account/releaseManagementService/_apis/releaseManagement/ConfigurationService/ListReleases

As of now I won't be able to find any related documentation on msdn or any other blog. Can somebody from release manger experts team suggest me if it is correct way to load release data.

Also one more question, is this the non documented but the real api to communicate with RM?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely to the HTTP communication between the RM server and client, you'll be able to see the API that loads the release - when you open a release that was created earlier.

The API to get a single release is -

```
../_apis/releaseManagement/ConfigurationService/GetRelease?id=*ReleaseId*
```

This API is not documented anywhere, and yes - it is actually used to communicate with RM.

For a vNext release, the Url would look like this -

```
../_apis/releaseManagement/ReleaseV2Service/GetRelease?id=*ReleaseId*
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not an API intended for public consumption and that it is not recommended to build anything based off of that API because it could change radically with no warning.

Comment: Agreed Daniel. This is not intended for public consumption. But I guess updating the API at any time would break all existing clients as well, so it will not be an all-of-a-sudden break that see.